# Not able to retrive data from array

Tags: php, arrays, phpexcel

I am trying to parse an Excel file. I am able to get the contents of individual cells of the excel. I am unable to add the data I got from the cell into an array.

```
    function parseExcel($inputFileName){
    $mh = new MainHandler;
    //  Read your Excel workbook
    try {
        $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
    }catch(Exception $e) {
      die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
    }

    $Arr = array();
   //  Get worksheet dimensions
   $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
   $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
   $highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();

  for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){

    $myArray = array();

    for($col = 'A' ; $col <= $highestColumn ; $col++){
       $a = $sheet->getCell($col.$row);
       // echo "\n".$a;
       $myArray[] = $a;
    }
    // $Arr[] = $myArray;
   echo json_encode($myArray);
 }
 // echo json_encode($Arr);
}
```

The output i get is

```
  [{},{},{},{},{}][{},{},{},{},{}][{},{},{},{},{}]
```

What should be done to get the populated array as output?

Comment: Add ->getValue() after getCell() ?

Comment: I get the contents of each cell in the $a variable. I can view it by echo $a. But i am unable to add it to the array.

Comment: Why don't you look at using PHPExcel's built-in `toArray()` method? But your call to `getCell()` is getting a cell, not a value from a cell, as Bert has pointed out

Comment: I tried toArray() and rangeToArray() methods. I get the output as `Array` and `Notice: Array to string conversion in `.

Comment: If you try echoing an array, you will get `Array` displayed, and other errors.... those methods return a 2-dimensional array, a standard PHP 2-dimensional array, use normal PHP methods to access the values in that array